# QGIS 2.8 Composer - extent / overview ... change style

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have a working overview setup with a general map and a detail map. Since scales are pretty much different - general 1:100.000 and detail 1:750 - I would like to change from the standard style (red, semi transparent rectangle) to a symbol ... like a crosshairs. has someone figured out how to change (i.e. fully customize) overview-map styles ?

To be more precise ... I would like to use symbols instead of any kind of fills!

Answer (score 1):

It looks there are two options for working with different styles in different scales: using other (duplicate) layer or define scale dependant style.

**Option 1**

1. Duplicate the layer(s) you want to set different styles in different scale
2. Customize the style for duplicated layer
3. Update maps in Print Composer using appropriate layers
4. (Most important) Use 'lock layers' option in print composer item proporties for your different maps. Export the map.

[image: lock layer]

**Option 2**

1. Choose Rule-Based style for your layer(s)

[image: rule-based]
 2. Define scale range for the style

[image: scale range]

3. Export image also using 'Lock layers' and 'Lock styles for layers' options

---

Choosing the option is up to you. However, I recommend using first option for creating comperable maps (e.g. colour and black&white maps) (pretty much similar task) and the second one for scale-dependant view.

P.S. I didn't get if you already have different layers for different scale (you mentioned you want to use symbols instead of fills, what may mean using points instead of polygons). In this case, you need just the 'Lock layers' option. I wrote solutions for more common tasks (with no changing geometry).

Comment: thx for the information. i used to work with a concept that is basically the one you've discribed in your option one! and that works pretty well. option 2 is interessting - so far i didn't try that one ! thx for the input ! 
but i was looking for a way to change the extent-marker within the overview !
up to now i could figure out that i can change the fill-symbol into a centroid fill and choose a simple marker symbol ... which is pretty close to my question. but still this symbol seems to be transparent within the overview section of my map. ... so i think i am on the right way.